# Proof that $P(E \mid E \cup F) \geq P(E \mid F)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering if anyone knew of a proof for:

$$ P(E\mid E \cup F) \geq P(E\mid F) $$

I tried expanding it and got to this really ugly looking formula (I actually expanded even more but condensed it for the sake of typing this out):

$$ \frac{P(E)P(F) - P(E \cap F)(P(E) + P(F) - P(E \cap F))}{P(F)(P(E)+P(F)-P(E \cap F))} $$

Any help is appreciated. I really want to be able to understand how to get to this conclusion and I feel like I'm just going overboard with all of this expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the LHS,

$$P(E\mid E\cup F) = \frac{P(E\cap (E\cup F))}{P(E\cup F)}$$

By the absorption law, the numerator satisfies

$$\begin{align*}
E\cap(E\cup F) &= E\\
P(E\cap (E\cup F)) &= P(E)
\end{align*}$$

The whole fraction then becomes

$$\begin{align*}
P(E\mid E\cup F) &= \frac{P(E)}{P(E\cup F)}\\
&= \frac{P(E\cap F) + P(E\cap F^C)}{P(F) + P(E\cap F^C)}
\end{align*}$$

If $P(E\cap F^C)=0$, then the required inequality is satisfied. Otherwise, by the [mediant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties), since $\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} \le 1$ as a probability,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} &\le \frac{P(E\cap F) + P(E\cap F^C)}{P(F) + P(E\cap F^C)} &&\le \frac{P(E\cap F^C)}{P(E\cap F^C)}\\
P(E\mid F) &\le P(E\mid E\cup F) &&\le 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am wondering why $P(E \cup F) = P(F) + P(E \cap F^c)$. Is there something I can look up to learn how this works or is it supposed to be obvious? I was under the impression $P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(E \cap F)$.

Comment: Nevermind my last question I see you substituted in for $P(E)$ and canceled. Thank you so much for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $e:=P(E),f:=P(F),n:=P(E\cap F)$.  Then

$$ P(E\mid E \cup F) ={P(E\cap (E\cup F))\over P(E\cup F)}={P(E)\over P(E)+P(F)-P(E\cap F)}={e\over e+f-n}$$
$$P(E|F)={P(E\cap F)\over P(F)}={n\over f}.$$

Then
$${e\over e+f-n}=1-{f-n \over (e-n)+f}\geq 1-{f-n \over f}={n\over f},$$

where the inequality comes from the fact that $e,f\geq n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!